# Embed non-related task list into Powerapps as a sub form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am trying to set up a Power app for my company to help keep track of the trip planning process. The tasks are the same for every trip being planned.

Lists:
TaskList - (Name, Category, Attachments)
TripList- (Trip Name, cost, location, dates, overall task progress)

Powerapp Items:
Trip List Form - Connected to TripList
TaskGallery - Connected to TaskList including a Status combobox with a table ({Text:"Ongoing",Val:0.5},{Text: "Complete",Val:1}...)

What I need is a way to View,Edit, and update the TaskGallery status for each item.

I tried a Collection with the Trip Name and a nested Task List Table (Task Name and Status Combo Box), but it is reset on every refresh. I tried saving it separately to a Third Sharepoint, but the nested table does not save. I feel like I am so close, but stuck on a final step.

In Infopath and Access, I was able to use a subform, but PowerApps does not have this direct function..

I am stuck trying to save the Information from the gallery to my sharepoint.